# CSS: Display child <ul> beside parent <ul> with tops aligned

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` nested within a `<ul>`, eg:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

I have used jquery to slide the nested list out to the right of the first list so that they appear side by side. My issue is that the 2nd list has a bit of gap at the top, 2 list items high where 'extends' from its parent list item.

Because of my jquery navigation set up both ul have float left and position absolute. The only way I can align them is by setting a negative margin-top to the 2nd ul, but I want to avoid that.

Would anyone know of a way to make this possible?

My CSS: (note I have a JQuery onClick function that slides them to the right for various lenghts)

```
#menu UL
{
        position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 14px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
}

#menu UL LI UL
{
        position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 14px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
}
```

Comment: can you through together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @apaul34208 done here http://jsfiddle.net/KuyLE/

Comment: Your fiddle only has limited HTML, it would help to see what you have all put together, JS, CSS, HTML and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `top: 0px` on `UL LI UL` and you could set `margin-top: 0px;` on it if you wanted to get rid of those 14 pixels space at the top as well.

<kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KuyLE/1/)**</kbd>

```
UL
{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 14px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

UL LI UL
{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 14px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
    top: 0px;
}
```